# downloading files as a corrupted files in kohana

Tags: kohana-3

hi guys i'm facing problem with file upload and download in kohana

```
my controller is like this:


class Controller_Test extends Controller
{
     public function action_display()
     {
        $type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

          switch ($type)
          {
          case 'image/gif':
             $otype='.gif';   break;
         case 'image/jpeg':
         case 'image/pjpeg':
            $otype= '.jpg';   break;
         case 'image/png':
            $otype= '.png';   break;
          case 'application/octet-stream':
              $otype='.doc';   break;
          case 'txt': $otype='.txt'; break;
          case 'application/pdf': $otype='.pdf'; break;
           }
     //rename the file
     $name = time() . '_' . mt_rand(1000,9999).$otype;
     $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].URL::base().'media';

      //uploading a file 
     $filename = Upload::save($_FILES['file'],  $name, $directory);

           $this->auto_render = false;
           $this->response->send_file($filename);

    }//action
}//controller
```

when i call this function file uploaded fine

but downloading file as a corrupted file

help me how to solve this..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add `URL::base()` inside the path name as that could add something like "http://..." inside the file path. Try removing `URL::base()` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

To start, there's some simple debug checks you can do here.

- Is `$directory` valid?
- is `$filename` a valid file path, or is it `FALSE`? (See http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Upload#save)

I'm going to assume `$directory` is invalid.

You want to use the absolute path constants to build directory paths. Instead of using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].URL::base()` (which is wrong in any case)

Rather use `APPPATH` or `DOCROOT`, eg `$directory = APPPATH.'media';` see https://github.com/kohana/kohana/blob/3.2/master/index.php#L57-74

Comment: @Badsystax `$directory` is valid and file uploaded successfully
problem is when i'm downloading same file it will download corrupted file

Comment: @Ratna how can `$directory` be valid when you are using `URL::base()`?

Comment: @Ratna are you absolutely certain there are no errors before sending the file in the response? How about trying to uncomment that line to see if any errors are generated..

Comment: @Ratna and are you certain there are no errors before sending the file to the browser? Is there any whitespace at the top or bottom of the controller file?

Comment: @Badsystax : actually i created directory(folder) in my project(ratnaKohana)  with name `'media'` here 
` $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ` gives `E:/xampp/htdocs' and 
`'URL::base()' gives /ratnaKohana/ '` 
`$directory gives "E:/xampp/htdocs/ratnaKohana/media" `

Comment: there are no errors before sending the file and there is no white spaces in the controller

Comment: **could you please suggest one good book for kohana ?? or send any link**

Comment: when i trying to download file in kohana using $this->response->send_file($path); method

i'm getting this Error

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpeg:`